# Class Weight not supported for 3+ dimensional targets - Python Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

i'm newbie in Deep Learning and i'm trying to implement a Convolutional Neural Network. 
When i fit the model, i pass 3 variables:

**- Predict_Representation:** An 4D matrix with shape (7, 255,355,54) - This matrix is composed by 7 samples of an 1-Hot Encoded from image.

**- Target Representation:** An 4D matrix with shape (7, 255,355,10) - This is the target matrix composed by 7 samples with 10 classes

**- Class Weight:** A dict composed by 10 elements, with the weight for each class

The problem is: When i fit the model, it shows me this error ---
"ValueError: `class_weight` not supported for 3+ dimensional targets."

What is the best way to correct this error?
Below, i will show this part of code
[image]